# Cordova/Touch onclick events issues

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I use a lot of onclick events on buttons in my HTML pages normally, following this pattern :

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)"></button>
```

Some work, Somedon't, and I can't explain why.

These work :

```
<div>
    <button class="static" onclick="myFunction('add');" style="">zzzzzzzzzzz</button>
    <button class="static" onclick="myFunction('res');" style="">zzzzzzzzzzz</button>
    <button class="static" onclick="myFunction('set');" style="">zzzzzzzzzzz</button>
</div>
```

These don't :

```
<center>
    <button onclick="newEdit(this)" class="pop_opt" style="height: 35px;">Edit</button>
    <hr/>
    <button onclick="newConfirm(this);" class="pop_opt" style="height: 35px;">Delete</button>
    <hr/>
    <button onclick="defaultPopup(this, '')" class="pop_opt" style="height: 35px;">Cancel</button>
</center>
```

The only differences I see are :

1. The first buttons are the first clickable elements (they are only clickable elements on area).
2. The others buttons are clickable elements over another clickable element (and normally if the buttons are clicked it should deny the parent click event).

*Note that it perfectly work in Desktop Browser, but only match issues when we use it in an App (I tested only with Cordova)*

Comment: use tap event http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp

Comment: you have to bind these events in device ready functions

Comment: but why some work and some other don't?

Comment: @kishore.k.vaishnav : I tried using jQuery (native) click events and they don't work either on those specified buttons (second group, still while working in browser).

Can it have anything to do with Cordova?

When you suggest me going jQuery Mobile, why would it work more?

Comment: @HassanALi : Why using device ready? I placed the JS scripts later in the HTML file (in this order : cordova.js jquery.min.js share.min.js)

Comment: because that's the way cordova work . Haven't you looked its basic example.

Comment: I would prefer not to go with a another 200ko file to load for such basic tasks, I'll try touchend instead of .click()

Comment: That said, I looked at the docs and it says it is used when we want to use device API (I don't for this script).
I tried adding all the JS in the callback of deviceready, it don't works more.

Comment: @HassanALi : is not solution

Comment: I finally resolved it with native solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could resolve this by simply changing the HTML event `onclick` to `onmousedown` & `ontouchend`